# Paginate Laravel Relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have two tables let's say posts and comments with Post and Comment Model.

```
Post.php

public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}

Comment.php

public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

Now I want to load Post with comments with pagination on both Post and comments.

What I tried so far,

```
   Post::with('comments')->pagenate();
```

The above code only paginates on Post Model. So I tried the following code but no luck.

```
In Post.php

public function comments(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class)->paginate(5);
}

Post::with('comments')->pagenate();
```

Answer (score -1):

In the controller you must put the Post variable and for each post the Comments variable with it paginate, then you return the variables.

```php
$posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);

foreach ($posts as $post)
        $comments = $post->comments()->paginate(2);

return view('post.index', ['posts' => $posts, 'comments' => $comments]);
```

Now, in the blade view, you only need to put the @foreach of the comments variable in the post and add the links to page it for you.

```php
@foreach( $comments as $comment )
   <p> {{ $comment->desc }}</p>
@endforeach

{{ $comments->links() }}
```